# how to find routes between two nodes based on table data in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to store sites and sites connections for example Site A is connected to site B and C. B is connected to A and E. C is connected to A and D. D is connected to C, G and F. F is connected to D and E. E is connected to F,B,J and H. H is only connected to E. When I want to select two sites for example from site A to J so It must show me all the possible routes from site A to J for example there is only two routes  the first is A-B-E-J and the second is A-C-D-F-E-J. I am using oracle and oracle apex so suggest me the tables structures and also how to achieve this task

Comment: @Littlefoot can you solve this problem